# Vimeo API: video search syntax

Tags: regex, vimeo, vimeo-api

Interested can I search using regexp-pattern or at least words that begin with the letter "a*"?

[Documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/) does not contain the required description.

Comment: Which search are you using? The vimeo API currently has two different search workflows.

Comment: Search for videos: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#